# what does "former colonies" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Independence, argued Paine, would free the **former colonies** from being entangled in European wars in which they had no concern.
>   A declaration of independence would also improve their chances of
>   securing foreign aid.

source: [DIPLOMACY](https://books.google.com/books?id=bZhRzR5xo78C&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=Independence,%20argued%20Paine,%20would%20free%20the%20former%20colonies%20from%20being%20entangled%20in%20European%20wars%20in%20which%20they%20had%20no%20concern.%20A%20declaration%20of%20independence%20would%20also%20improve%20their%20chances%20of%20securing%20foreign%20aid.&source=bl&ots=EQhUsImqo1&sig=7jFY3AEE57yZJ8sVlYvQhakb6cA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivueeB2NLNAhXDSRoKHcy0BAUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Independence%2C%20argued%20Paine%2C%20would%20free%20the%20former%20colonies%20from%20being%20entangled%20in%20European%20wars%20in%20which%20they%20had%20no%20concern.%20A%20declaration%20of%20independence%20would%20also%20improve%20their%20chances%20of%20securing%20foreign%20aid.&f=false)
does it mean previously or making?

Comment: The 13 initial states comprising the USA were colonies of the Great Britain before declaring their independence. When Paine was advancing his argument, they were still technically colonies. Note that the word "would" is used.

Comment: You seem to be going through this text and asking questions about it, so I suggest you read it through and write down what you don't understand. Then, you can ask about what you don't understand in one question rather than many.

Comment: @eijen That's actually specifically discouraged here... please don't tell people to use one question to ask many questions at the same time. Every question should stand on its own so that it can be individually addressed.

Comment: @eijen **Explicitly** discouraged. @ yorgun Please continue to have one question per post and include your thoughts and research. Thank you.

Comment: My apologies. I thought it would be easier for him to collate things, but of course that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @all and thanks to probablyme.
i think we can use both of meaning of FORMER:
1- previously colonies of Great Britain  and
2- colonies that Founded independence.
which one is precise meaning of text? you (as native english speakers) can answer correctly. if we use 1st meaning. then how pine used FORMER for colonies that was still not gained independence???

Answer (score 2):

Usually the phrase "the former colonies" is used idiomatically to refer to colonies of England that won or otherwise gained independence, and usually to refer specifically to the United States.

Generally, the phrase "former colonies" means "places that used to be ruled by a colonial government but are not ruled by a colonial government now."

Comment: i think we can use both of meaning of FORMER:
1- previously colonies of Great Britain  and
2- colonies that Founded independence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case "previously" is correct.

> [former](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/former)
>
> - Having been so in the past
> - having been at a previous time

Paine is specifically talking about the states that were *once* colonies, they were previously colonies. We understand this from context. You can imagine that in a different context, *former colonies* could refer to other colonies that England had, since England had many colonies throughout the world. In fact, *former colonies* by itself could refer to any regions that were once colonies (of any ruling power).

Another example of the use of *former* is

> former President [George W. Bush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush).

He was previously the President of the United States, but now he isn't.